# I couldn't able to install apache tomcat in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qubGf.jpg)

the above error is popping up

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jx8L.jpg)

previously I already have tomcat 10 and was working fine. For new project I want to run in tomcat 9. but getting error while installing. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLTbs.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Reported and fixed with bug [582541](https://bugs.eclipse.org/582541), in the 2023-12 release. The digits in the service release number were transposed.